# Does the Python interpreter check indents to be space or tab characters?

Tags: python

For example are 4 space characters equivalent to 1 tab character for new line indents? 
Or will it only scan for just one and not the other?

Comment: A line can be indented with one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ “can” in what context?

Comment: @Ry- "Can" in the context that you decide not to follow PEP8, which says 4 spaces per indent :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I mean: are you saying *logically* a line can be indented with one or the other but not both? That would be true. The Python interpreter isn’t going to stop you, though.

Comment: @Ry- Ah, yeah... one or the other for the interpreter to not throw any SyntaxErrors...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: You can indent a line with both. No SyntaxError.

Comment: @Ry- Interesting. If I indent with spaces first and _then_ a tab, it throws a SyntaxError, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.x (and Python 2.x when passed `-tt`) will refuse to run code with mixed tabulation.

Python 2.x without `-tt` will run code with mixed tabulation, and consider a tab to be equivalent to a run of 8 spaces.

(And Python 2.x with `-t` will run it, but complain.)